# How to check Only Credit card number is valid not Debit card..?

Tags: c#, algorithm, validation, paypal, credit-card

im using this code for checking credit card number valid or not. But in this code checking both number credit and debit.

I want only credit card number checking.

```
private bool IsValidNumber(string number)
    {
        int[] DELTAS = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0 };
        int checksum = 0;
        char[] chars = number.ToCharArray();
        for (int i = chars.Length - 1; i > -1; i--)
        {
            int j = ((int)chars[i]) - 48;
            checksum += j;
            if (((i - chars.Length) % 2) == 0)
                checksum += DELTAS[j];
        }

        return ((checksum % 10) == 0);
    }
```

Thanks, Kaushik.

Comment: I think you are going to have to define how you know a number is a credit card number vs a debit card number.   To my knowledge there is no way to see from the number it self what kind of card it is only the banks know.    However this may be different across banks and countries

Comment: @DaImTo you didnt get my point. i want to check customer entered creditcard number is valid or not

Comment: How do you know if the number is valid or not?  Has the card company given you a spec that says 124 is valid credit card and 789 is a valid debit card?  How do you know there is a pattern that defines credit card numbers vs debit card numbers?  You cant create an algorithm to test a pattern that doesn't exist.

Comment: Maybe stupid question, but why do you need to distinguish? When the card is valid, why do you care how the customer pays? Whether the card is valid and not blocked can only be known if you contact the bank.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are going to have to define how you know a number is a credit card number vs a debit card number. To my knowledge there is no way to see from the number it self what kind of card it is only the banks know. However this may be different across banks and countries.

Comment: It is possible to determine of a card is a debit card or not. We do it in our billing and payments platform.

Comment: @JohnConde mind answering the question with how you are doing it.    In Europe we have been unable to do this.   Currently we attempt to charge the card if the bank rejects due to debit card we know its the wrong type.   If you have a way of validating the cards without sending a charge i would love to hear it.

Comment: I'll have to see if I can get the info from the team that did the work as I do not have all of the details myself.

Comment: @John, I get the impression you work at a PSP and so probably have access to the IIN updates published by the ABA which contain this information. Without access to the latest IIN (card range) updates I don't think this is possible.